# feathers update service cleans document

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io, feathersjs

I have a problem because something is wrong with my service update. I have correctly created model. For example, when I use below service:

```
app.service('teachers').update(_id, { $set: { "name": "firstName" }});
```

my document is cleaned instead update. There is only one field left:

```
{"_id":ObjectId("...")}
```

I logged in console and $set it was picked up. I checked it this way:

```
update: [
    function(context){

       console.log(context.data);
    }
]
```

log shows:

```
{ $set: { "name": "firstName" }}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The query is okay. I think you need to add more info, the feathers service adapter you are using and the version.

Comment: I use feathers version 3.8.6 and feathers-mongoose version 6.2.0 I installed node v6.11.3 and updated all packages. I updated my question: I added log